# Convert Array of time in seconds to HH:MM format python

Tags: python

I have an array of integers with data in seconds like:
time = (900,1800,2700,...)
and would like to convert it into an array with the following format:
time_new = (hh:mm,hh:mm,...)

Comment: What code have you tried to solve this?

Comment: Seconds from what?  Midnight?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Will you need AM/PM or will it be 24 hour time?

Comment: _(hh:mm,hh:mm,...)_ Are those strings or `datetime.time` objects?

Comment: So input of `timedelta` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

with output of `strftime` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, below is how I fixed the data:

```
 def convert(seconds):
            seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600)
            hour = seconds // 3600
            seconds %= 3600
            minutes = seconds // 60
            seconds %= 60
              
            return "%d:%02d" % (hour, minutes)
        time = []
        for i in range(size_of_time):
            time.append(str(convert(times[i])))
```

Comment: Why are you calling `str()` on the output of a function that already returns a string?

Comment: leftover from a different solution that didn't work